# save to local storage swift

Tags: ios, swift, save, local-storage

I am designing an idle clicker style app, as I am quite new to programming and thought it would be a good personal project. However I am trying to design the upgrades on a second ViewController menu, however every time that the user leaves the first ViewController, all the settings on that page are lost e.g. stats. I know that there are already similar questions, but they don't relate to my issue and I am having difficulties trying to understand them.

I was just wondering if someone had any way to save this progress both when the user moves to a new viewController and when the app is closed and reopened. Also this might be pushing it, but if you could describe what each part of the code does it would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: there are loads of options for storing data in iOS, you should do some research on the various options to see what works best for your needs. The usual suspects would be UserDefaults (usually best for storing small settings, flags), core data, realm, firebase and others

Comment: I would personally recommend [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest), far easier to set up than CoreData and Firebase

Comment: Well worded question! As long as the data you wish to store is small and local (stored on the device and not in the cloud), I suggest you look into what was suggested in the answer - `UserDefaults`.

Answer (score 1):

Best is to use `UserDefaults` to store page contents. You can define key/value pairs and save and load values as needed. Look for it in the IOS documentation. It is very easy to implement it.